# Adding IF Exist to truncate statement while looping through DBs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, truncate

Please, I am trying to add if exists statement to the code below such that it only print truncate statements on all DBs where the table= dbo.log only exist. (SQL Server 2016)

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
                 AND  TABLE_NAME = 'log'))

BEGIN
    PRINT 'Table Exists'
END

--Truncate log from db like'OG_%'
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @sql = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), (
    SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), 'TRUNCATE TABLE ') + QUOTENAME(name) + '.dbo.log; '
    FROM sys.databases
        WHERE NAME LIKE  'OG_%%'
         FOR XML PATH('')
))
PRINT(@sql)
--EXEC(@sql)
```

Thanks

Comment: [Dont use Information schema](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views) . This answer covers your solution https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/210177/8783